# how to do terms and agreement show only once for one user?

Tags: angularjs, logic

I have a login page,

when a user login for the first time it should show the terms and agreement popup with accept button.
if user is accepted it for the first time . when user login for next time popup should not come.

i want to use local storage for this function no db changes allowed.

so what i have to save in localstorage. the scenario is complex when this has to work for diffrent users.

in angularjs i m using ngstorage plugin.
 i can save data into local storage like

```
      $localStorage.data="username";
```

in this case how i have to save for diffrent diffrent user?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a key value pair, where key indicates the username and value indicate whether it has been loaded or not and push them into an array.

Something like this,

```
var testObj = { 'John': true };
// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('John', JSON.stringify(testObject));
```

Similarly for all the users.

Then retrieved by using username,

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('John');
console.log('User has already loaded: ', JSON.parse(John));
```

[`DEMO APP USING angular-local-storage`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/0arf1mhq/)

Comment: is this using ngstorage?

Comment: This is using local storage, you can use the same concept for ngStorage too

Comment: localstorage is inbuilt or i have to instll it?

Comment: localstorage is inbuilt in any web app, but if you are using angularjs its better to go with ngStorage

Comment: @Vispriya Check the sample app